# For each $n \in \Bbb N$ define $h_n(x)=|x|^{\frac 1n}$ on $[0,1]$. Prove that the family $\{h_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is not equi-continuous on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, proof-verification

My try:

> Let $(\frac 1{2^n})$ and $(\frac 1{3^n})$ be two sequences in $[0,1]$.Then
>
> $|\frac 1{2^n}- \frac 1{3^n}| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty.$
>
> But $|h_n(\frac 1{2^n})-h_n(\frac 1{3^n})|=|\frac 12 - \frac 13|=\frac 16$ $\forall n$.
>
> Hence the family is not equi-continuous.
>
> Here what we have done is that we have found an $\epsilon \gt 0$ (in this case $\frac 16$) such that for any $\delta \gt 0$ we can find points $x,y \in [0,1]$ (in this case $\frac 1{2^k}$ and $\frac 1{3^k}$) and a function $f$ (in this case $h_k$) such that $|x-y| \lt \delta$ but $|f(x)-f(y)| \ge \epsilon$. This is exactly the negation of the definition of Equi-continuity.

Is my proof and understanding correct?

Comment: Correct. It's equivalent to showing that your sequence does not preserve limits, for example at 0.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution using [Ascoli-Arzelà](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem): the sequence is obviously uniformly bounded. If it were also equicontinuous, should have a uniformly convergent subsequence. But this is impossible as the pointwise limit is discontinuous.